# Render HTML code based on multiple conditions using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have several items that I want to render using the [`Array#map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate  over them and return the desired elements. However, there are some conditions in which the HTML will be built.

Here's the code:

```
<span className="items-overview">
    {
    this.props.obj.items.map((item, index) => {

        return (
            (item.LeftParenthesis ? "<b>" + item.LeftParenthesis + "</b>" : "")
            + "<i>" + item.Description + "</i>"
            + (item.RightParenthesis ? "<b>" + item.RightParenthesis + "</b>" : "")
            + (item.LogicOperand && index < this.props.obj.Conditions.length - 1 ? "&nbsp;<span>" + item.LogicOperand + "</span>" : "") + "&nbsp;"                                 
        )            
    })
    }
</span>
```

The result is the following(assuming there's only one item):

[image]

**Approaches I've tried**

1. I know I could have multiple IF statements or a switch statement to determine what to return, but this would be a bit messy. I prefer to avoid this
2. I really don't want to use [dangerously-set-inner](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use strings:

```
return (
  <span>
    {
      item.LeftParenthesis &&
        <b>{item.LeftParenthesis}</b>
    }
    <i>{item.Description}</i>
    {
      item.RightParenthesis &&
        <b>{item.RightParenthesis}</b>
    }
    {
      item.LogicOperand && index < this.props.obj.Conditions.length - 1 &&
        <span>&nbsp;{item.LogicOperand}</span>           
    }
    &nbsp;          
  </span>
)
```

This will add a few more `span`s to your HTML hierarchy so that React may correctly render everything. This uses [React's conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) to render elements based on a condition.

This isn't a workaround, this is the correct way to conditionally render elements.

Comment: This worked like a charm! I only had to arrange some CSS rules because of the span element. Thank you sir!

Comment: @ggderas No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use actual react components instead of strings?

You can use components that will only render if the condition is true
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

```
<span className="items-overview">
    {this.props.obj.items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <span>
                {item.LeftParenthesis && <b>{item.LeftParenthesis}</b>}
                <i>{item.Description}</i>
                {item.RightParenthesis && <b>{item.RightParenthesis}</b>}
                {item.LogicOperand && index < this.props.obj.Conditions.length - 1 && (&nbsp;<span>{item.LogicOperand}</span>)}
                &nbsp;
            </span>                                       
        );
    )}
</span>
```

Comment: This is still invalid syntax.